# Finding cycle in graph with parent-child relationship and dependencies between elements

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm working with a project where we have a Task and Folder, which can contain Task or other Folders.
Each Task has its own duration and duration for Folder equals to earliest task start and latest task finish, example:

[image: Project structure]

And each element can depend on other in one of 4 ways (Finish to start (FS), Finish to finish (FF), Start to start (SS), Start to finish (SF)) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_(project_management)

I'm trying to figure out, how algorithmically find if adding new dependancy will create a cycle in a case where it's allowed to create dependancies with folders.

With dependencies only between tasks it's not hard to imagine it as an oriented graph, where Task is a node and each dependency is an edge, then use something similar to DFS to find cycles. (FF and SS dependencies make it more complicated)

But when you also can connect folders with tasks/folders, it becomes much harder, because folder by default has dependencies with its childs, except that this dependency is oriented both ways and Task/Folder can get moved when you create dependency with other

Here's an example of cycle which I try to find (folders are grey, "bad" dependency is red), connected tasks have opposite dependency compared to their parents

[image: cycle]

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this by constructing the graph from the dependencies between tasks ONLY.

If the start of B folder depends on the end of A folder, then use dependency between the last task in A and the first task in B.

[image]

```
t1->t2
t2->t3
t3->t4
t4->t2
```

Then use a cycle finder on this graph